# How to set title into route in Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes

I have a routing like this 'xxx.com/company/880'

```
  { path: 'company/:id', component: CompanyComponent }
```

In a component I am subscribing on route.params, get id of company and then get data by id.

I need to change the route to look something like this 'xxx.com/company/880/NameOfCompany' but when change id of company manually in url and so that the name of the company changes too

Comment: This is not a good to practice to inject the name With id in your url. This is redundant. Why do you want to achieve this ? Is it for pure aesthetic ?

Comment: You should need a backend endpoint where you can get the company by name. Adding path parameter `'company/:name'`. Load the company data by name.